# Get back changes which were removed due to undo operation in TFS?

Tags: tfs

Mistakenly, I did undo operation on my TFS checkout and I lost all my changes.

Is there a way to get back changes or reverse of undo operation?

I checked, I can not restore with Windows restore option.

Comment: I think you are SOL unless you saved it in a changeset.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/712901/get-back-changes-which-were-removed-due-to-undo-operation-in-tfs  Do not post the same question twice please.

Comment: Actually, I did not save and I have not been working with few things for sometime and I do not know, where and what changes I made during past few months.

Comment: @KevinPanko: I posted same question tehre as well because I was not getting answer here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not through any mechanism that TFS provides; when you undo a pending change, the original contents of the file at your workspace version will be placed on disk, overwriting any changes you've made.

You may be able to use some undeletion tool to recover the file contents.

In the future, you may use TFS shelvesets to back up your changes to the server.

Comment: Can you suggest me any undeletion tool?

Comment: Just for future work, I would recommend you to use something like that: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/080540cb-e35f-4651-b71c-86c73e4a633d